# xcode - how to write 100% in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

i have an issue,

```
htmltext = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<style>width:100%"
```

and the percentage (%) have a warning : invalid conversion specifier '"'

how we write percentage in obj c which is i write on webview.

thanks!

Comment: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Value: 100%%"];

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this -

```
htmltext = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<style>width:100%%"];
```

Use %% which escapes the %.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `%%` which escapes the `%`.

However, if you don't have any parameters (as in your example) then you should just use:

```
htmltext = @"<style>width:100%";
```